# Count lines of multiple files (Using minted for formatting.)

Tags: minted, loops, line-numbering

I am using minted to show source code in my document like this:

```
\section{Image functions}
\inputminted{python}{src/imagefuncs.py}

\section{Matrix operations}
\inputminted{python}{src/matrices.py}

\section{Block operations}
\inputminted{python}{src/blocks.py}
```

and so on for several files. Is there a way to count the number of lines in these files and output a total.

Python pseudo code:

```
paths = ['src.py', 'matrices.py', 'blocks.py']
total = 0
for path in paths:
    total += linecount(path)
print(str(total))
```

Any similar questions I found were for listings and only one file.

Edit: To be clear, I want to do this in latex, the python code is to illustrate.

Comment: you can use python inside tex with the `python` library. You can check for example [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269207/9335).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a key, which I call `addlines` to the `\inputminted` commands you want the total number of lines is taken care of.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test1.py}
paths = ['src.py', 'matrices.py', 'blocks.py']
total = 0
for path in paths:
    total += linecount(path)
print(str(total))
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{test2.py}
paths = ['src.py', 'matrices.py', 'blocks.py']
total = 0
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\define@key{minted@opt@cmd}{addlines}[true]{\csname @addlines#1\endcsname}
\xpatchcmd{\inputminted}
  {\endgroup}
  {\if@addlines\addtocounter{totallines}{\value{FancyVerbLine}}\fi\endgroup}
  {}{}
\newif\if@addlines
\newcounter{totallines}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\inputminted[addlines]{python}{test1.py}
\inputminted[addlines]{python}{test2.py}

The total number of code lines is \thetotallines

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following code will print the code listing and a line count (global). Please note that this is definitely not the most efficient approach.

[image: linecount]

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: 1 }
%!TeX TS-program=arara
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}

\begin{filecontents*}{test1.py}
paths = ['src.py', 'matrices.py', 'blocks.py']
total = 0
for path in paths:
    total += linecount(path)
print(str(total))
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{test2.py}
paths = ['src.py', 'matrices.py', 'blocks.py']
total = 0
\end{filecontents*}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \g__ole_lines_int
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \__ole_countlines:n #1
    {
        \ior_open:Nn \g_tmpa_ior { #1 }
        \ior_str_map_inline:Nn \g_tmpa_ior
            { \int_gincr:N \g__ole_lines_int }
        \ior_close:N \g_tmpa_ior
    }
\NewDocumentCommand { \inputcode } { m }
    {
        \inputminted { python } { #1 }
        \__ole_countlines:n { #1 }
    }
\NewDocumentCommand { \showlines } { }
    {
        \int_use:N \g__ole_lines_int
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\inputcode{test1.py}
\showlines
\inputcode{test2.py}
\showlines
\end{document}
```